# How to expose Consumer service for kafka as continuous listener

Tags: spring, cxf, spring-integration, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a java program where I have written Consumer for [kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/) topic.! to continuously listen the topic by Consumer in while loop.
For better design and scaling while loop is not good idea. Is there any solution or example using which I can spawn threads which can consume Kafka topic continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, your question isn't clear. Please, share something like: I have this, but would like to have this. And I, personally, don't understand that concept like "expose a listener service"...

Although if you are looking for something like Spring solution, please, take a look into the particular project on the matter - [Spring for Apache Kafka](http://projects.spring.io/spring-kafka/).

And if we are talking about [Spring Integration](http://projects.spring.io/spring-integration/) here, pay attention, please, to the particular chapter in the Spring Kafka Reference Manual.

Comment: I have tried to improve question based on your inputs, will try to improvise again if you suggest as I am bit new to kafka space .

Comment: Great! As I answered you: read Spring Kafka manual and that library. The KafkaListenerContainer does the stuff for you. It is really polling Kafka topic in the while loop, in its special thread.